# What if the Islamic religion was never founded?

Tags: religion, alternate-history, history

Before Mohammed founded the Islam religion, the weak and religiously divided Arabian tribes fought each other on the Arabian Peninsula in the shadow of the powerful Byzantine Empire. Without Islam becoming the common religion of the region, this would have been going on and on until they were assimilated by the Byzantine Empire. So the Osman Empire would have never existed and Byzantine Empire would have remained a strong superpower.

Could this result in a more peaceful future? Or the opposite, with wars between the Catholic and Orthodox empires, leading to a conflict similar to the Christian-Islamic one? What might be the result of this alternative history?

*Note: I asked this question on the History stack, but was advised to ask it here since alt history is off-topic there.*

Comment: This belongs on alternate history,

Comment: @CAgrippa - there's no alt history site per se. This site is the closest to that we have.

Comment: The issue is not what the religion tells us to do, there are always someone trying to manipulate the innocent through misuse of religious concept that give rise to conflict.

Comment: @user6760 Yust for clarification: I have no problem with the islam religion at all. It is not worser or better than any other religion. (I do not follow any.) And you are right, all common religions have been used for such purposes that are not compatible with this religion. (Holly  Wars, i.e.) But the question has nothing to do with teology, rather with historical political events.

Comment: I vote to close because this question is **far** too broad to answer, and highly subjective.

Comment: @o.m. I disaggree. My question has barely anything to do with teological questions, it is about an alternative history where the Osman Empire never existed and Byzanzine is remained the most powerful South-Europan empire.

Comment: @user4729, I wrote "too broad" and "highly subjective". An alternate history with a departure point more than 1,000 years before has no good answer. Say the Moors didn't go to the Iberian peninsula, Charles Martel did something else than in the real world, Charlemagne is never crowned, and there **is no catholic empire**. Or an unopposed Frank empire **conquers the world.** Both possible outcomes.

Comment: @o.m. To some extent you are right, we can not give an exact answer to this. But I doubt that it would be too broad or subjective: the history is quite predictable sometimes. Hadn't Byzantium have problems with the islamic tribes, it remained the most powerful and the leader country of orthodox religion. The catholics, with no hostile religion and so a common enemy nearby, would have started fighting each other, resulting a conflict between Rome and Byzantium comparable to the christian-islamic one. We can't tell exactly what will be 1000 years later, but this was not the main question.

Comment: This is potentially a great question but the others are right, at the moment it's too broad. You need to focus on a short time period after the change or somehow focus it. You can ask what happens one or two steps after the initial change but after that butterflies and chaos means anything can happen.

Comment: Of course once you've decided what happens after a few steps feel free to ask a follow on question to that. The problem is the explosion of possibilities that happens if the development of the alt history is unconstrained.

Comment: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3223/49

Answer (score 0):

Every evolving empire finds and uses some religion of one or another kind (communism including). It is a disaster for religion, as the need to serve official daily goals, this so known "[Gott mit uns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gott_mit_uns)", often undermines the crucial values for which the prophets were ready to die, and many did. Islam has been in this role but also Christianity, also even Atheism.

It would have been great success for Islam not to serve in this role. As for Empire, seems not a problem. There is no lack of religions in the world and probably any can be adapted.

Comment: Atheism is not a religion.

Comment: No, it is. To believe nothing exists is also to believe. Atheism was the official religion of the Soviet Union.

Comment: @h22 That's false. ["USSR became the first state to have, ideological objective, the elimination of religion and its replacement with universal atheism."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_the_Soviet_Union) You're suggesting they elimiated religion and replaced it with religion? Would you also claim "bald" is a hair color?

Comment: In any case, my answer is "maybe would have been better for Islam but no impact on Osman Empire as any religion can be adapted for the need". Atheism is referred as religion by some sources, by others it is not, sorry for hitting sensitive topic by chance.

Comment: @Samuel - Yes. The replaced one set of irrational beliefs with another one. Whether you slap a different label on it, or not, is largely irrelevant to the framework structure (and if you consider absence of supernatural god figure a necessary attribute, plenty of Buddhists would be happy to assert that no, their faith is a real religion despite not having theistic component). I suggest you read Eric S. Raymond's blog, he writes on the topic much more lucidly than I can do it justice in comments..

Comment: +1. Islam had its pecularities that helped the Caliphate to grow fast - such as built in ethnic blindness and conversion at the tip of a sword being a Holy idea. However, lack of access to Islam haven't stopped any empires before (from Kir to Rome) nor after (from Temuchin to various Hapsburgs to Great Britain) from being aggressive expansionist empires. Islam was a contributing factor, not a cause, in how geopolitics got shaped in the last 1600 years

Comment: As usual, please see "is there a way to design a realistic religion?" The implicit definitions here all presume tenets and faith, and are therefore invalid as general definitions.

Comment: @h22 I belive that without the Islam these arabic tribes would have been quickly either converted to Christianity or subjugated by the Byzantian Empire. Thus, the Arab or later the Osman Empire would have been never existed.

Comment: @DVK What "framework structure" does atheism have? I must have missed getting my non-Holy book describing the tenants of not believing in one or more gods or other supernatural elements. I've read some of Eric's posts but I'm not seeing any claims as to atheism being a religion.

Comment: @DVK Things do not work that way. Not believing in something is not the same as believing it doesn't exist (though most religious folks will claim they *know* their god exists rather than say they only believe it). It's also not faith. Do you have *faith* that I am not ten meters tall or do you just reasonably infer it to be unlikely given your experience in the world?

Comment: Since there seems to be a bunch of preconceived notions about what atheism is and is not, as an atheist, I would like to clear things up with this: [Atheism is not a belief system nor is it a religion.](http://atheists.org/activism/resources/what-is-atheism?).

Comment: @DVK So... Providing a link to the American Atheists organization where the idea of atheism is clearly explained as not religious is equivalent to referencing a religious work of literature that has been reinterpreted countless times over the last two millennia? I must be missing something, because that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DVK No, I'm not. I provided a link to an external site and allowed you to draw your own conclusions about it. Can we agree that we have different ideas about what atheism is and leave it at that? This isn't the appropriate venue for this discussion.

Comment: @Samuel Bald is a hair style, though not always one's first choice. You need to compare like things if you hope to make your point by comparisons.

Comment: * citation needed 
"Every evolving empire finds and uses some religion of one or another kind"    Really all of them?  It seems like you are assuming most counties had a religion -> expanding empires require a religion as the basis